# Something weird about div and text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I have four divs where the first div have something and the last three is empty.

```
<div id="simple">Value (Required) - As Is - Office<div>
<div id="simple2"><div>
<div id="simple3"><div>
<div id="simple4"><div>
```

I get the content of the first div split it and put the result into the next three div.

```
var ahtml = $("#simple").html();
alert(ahtml);
var bhtml = ahtml.split("-");
alert(bhtml[0]);
$("#simple2").text(bhtml[0]);
alert(bhtml[1]);
$("#simple3").text(bhtml[1]);
alert(bhtml[2]);
$("#simple4").text(bhtml[2]);
```

For some reason it is not working in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcLNm/2/) <-- the link. The last two are not being outputed and when i get the html of the first div the alert is really weird. Am I forgetting something? Any ideas?

Comment: Surel you mean `</div>` not `<div>`. This lack of closing tag is probably really messing with jQuery/Sizzle

Comment: @PaulSullivan LOL omg hahaha this is embarrassing. Thnx

Comment: Just a side note: I would use console.log instead of alert. Really less aggressive.

Comment: @AlexP wierd last time I use console.log it did not work but now it did. hmmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close  element:

```
<div id="simple">Value (Required) - As Is - Office</div>
<div id="simple2"></div>
<div id="simple3"></div>
<div id="simple4"></div>
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/bcLNm/5/

Comment: Opps hahaha this is embarrassing. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Possibly caused by your lack of closing tag for each div i.e.

```
<div id="simple">Value (Required) - As Is - Office<div>
<div id="simple2"><div>
<div id="simple3"><div>
<div id="simple4"><div>
```

should be

```
<div id="simple">Value (Required) - As Is - Office</div>
<div id="simple2"></div>
<div id="simple3"></div>
<div id="simple4"></div>
```

Which is possibly causing all sorts of mischief in the sizzle engine in jquery

Answer (score 1):

You have to close your divs.

```
<div id="simple">Value (Required) - As Is - Office</div>
<div id="simple2"></div>
<div id="simple3"></div>
<div id="simple4"></div>
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bcLNm/3/).